# MIMIC-III. Select only the first ICU admission

Tags: mimic-iii

How can I select data only for the first ICU stay of each patient? In the MIMIC-II, there was a column with the sequence of ICU stay (first, second) and another column with the `icustay_id`. In the MIMIC-III, `icustay_id` does not appear to be a good identifier. For example in the prescription table, there are many rows with `subject_id` but no `icustay_id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patients may move between various care units over a single hospital admission. MIMIC-III provides significantly more detail than MIMIC-II about these movements thanks to the addition of the [transfers table](http://mimic.physionet.org/mimictables/transfers/).

[As noted](http://mimic.physionet.org/mimictables/icustays/) in the MIMIC documentation, `icustay_id` is an identifier that has been generated using the transfers table for convenience of analysis. The hospital and ICU databases are not intrinsically linked and they do not share the concept of an ICU encounter.

> "In the MIMIC-III, `icustay_id` does not appear to be a good identifier. For example in the prescriptions table, there are many rows with `subject_id` but no `icustay_id`."

Many of the entries in the [prescriptions table](http://mimic.physionet.org/mimictables/prescriptions/) do not have an `icustay_id` because the order times are not easily associated with a single ICU stay. For example, many prescriptions do not occur while the patient was in the ICU. In these cases it could be misleading to associate the order with any one particular ICU stay, so the `icustay_id` field is null.

> "How can I select data only for the first ICU stay of each patient?"

Code has been shared in the [MIMIC Code Repository](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code) for creating an [icustay_detail table](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/tree/master/concepts/demographics). The table includes an `icustay_seq` column which would allow you to select only the first ICU stay for each patient:

```
SELECT distinct(icustay_id)
FROM icustay_detail
WHERE icustay_seq = 1;
```

To ensure that relevant data is included from sources like the prescriptions table, you could select data for these `icustay_id` using the `subject_id` along with restrictions on the `intime` and `outtime`. Whether or not you would like to include data in your analysis that occurs beyond the time of the ICU stays is a question that you might also want to consider.